# Can't fix file association after removing unwanted junkware

Tags: windows, malware, file-types

I am having issues with my Type of file parameter, and default opening. As you can see in the "open with" window, the option to select default is greyed out. On the left it says that the type of file is "NextCOup" which I have removed entirely, but this thing is a reminder of a bad memory, trying to uninstall that crapware after a careless free software install.

It is a plain text file (I checked in Linux) but varies as other text files aren't affected. This file is a readme of gpart usb install

I have tried various things and have searched on Google.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRvZO.jpg]

Comment: In folder options, can you uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types" and tell us what extension you see for the file in question. If you don't see *any* extension, that probably has something to do with your issue.

Comment: Hello, i followed your advice and there indeed isn't any extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem, here's what worked for me:

Start cmd as admin (on win8: press windows button; type *cmd*; <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

```
assoc .="No Extension"
```

Comment: Thank you! It was frustrating seeing the name of that virus every day. Much appreciated. Can't upvote because of reputation

Answer (score 0):

Windows identifies filetypes by the file extensions after the `.` in the filename. Normally the "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" button tells Windows to change which program you should use to open all other files with the same extension.

Your particular text file, however, does not have an extension after the filename. This is what is keeping you from changing the file association. If you rename the file to include a `.txt` extension, it should open in Notepad (or whatever other default program you choose to open text files) every time.

This "NextCOUp" probably somehow managed make itself the default program for all unknown filetypes. It is possible it modified the registry key at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown`.

Comment: thanks for your help, I think you are right about it changing a reg key but it didn't seem to be that particular one. but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently, malvertisements have been flooded the Internet. Starters' PC could be easily messed up with such annoying plus stubborn greyware, while an out-dated security client may be unable to fully protect newbie from those aggressive drive-by download -- technically, we'd call 'em as downware, or customized installer/ downloader: they live up with their names.

Once user run that wild setup file, those sponsored junkware could make theirselves the king of the programs list, browser configurations (e.g., homepage, search provider, etc) and related system settings.

At this point, I personally recommend that you:

1. Perform a virus scan regularly under Safe Mode using an up-to-date security software. Here, I'd recommend avast to U.
2. Clean potentially unwanted programs (aka, PUPs). Check out "Uninstall a program" >> force remove any other unwanted/ unknown items in the list via an uninstall tool pro if  Windows' uninstall utility does not help too much.
3. To avoid foistware and malware infection, DO scan your download via the recommended avast or Virstotal from Google. Be cautious when you run ad-based installer like some freeware even downware.

Thanks and take care.

Comment: yeah, i have had gosave three times now, i need to very careful when installing exes for those pesky pups! thanks for the tip about virstotal